# Changing dynamic values of text in column in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
 param           values
 pred_qc1_moves     345
 pred_qc2_moves     444
 pred_qc3_moves     333
 abc              23.54
 def              44.65
```

first 3 rows are generated dynamically. There are 6 rows in total `pred_1_moves,pred_2_moves,pred_3_moves,pred_4_moves,pred_5_moves,pred_6_moves`
There can be 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 such rows

I want to replace this text to following

```
 param               values
 Predicted QC1 Moves     345
 Predicted QC2 Moves     444
 Predicted QC3 Moves     333
 abc                   23.54
 def                   44.65
```

how can I do this in R?

Comment: `library(dplyr)`
`recode(df$param, 'pred_1_moves' = 'Predicted 1 Moves', 'pred_2_moves' = 'Predicted 2 Moves', 'pred_3_moves' = 'Predicted 3 Moves')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the revised example data, you can use:

```
sub("^pred_(.+)_moves$", "Predicted \\U\\1 Moves", df$param, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Predicted QC1 Moves" "Predicted QC2 Moves" "Predicted QC3 Moves"
#[4] "abc"                 "def"
```

---

You can do this with a single `sub` call by capturing the groups and replacing with the new values.

```
df$param <- sub("^(pred_)(\\d+)(_moves)$", "Predicted \\2 Moves", df$param)
#              param values
#1 Predicted 1 Moves 345.00
#2 Predicted 2 Moves 444.00
#3 Predicted 3 Moves 333.00
#4               abc  23.54
#5               def  44.65
```

The other rows that don't meet the criteria are left unchanged.

Comment: Thanks I was actually wondering if you could use `sub` to do this with a single call !

Comment: @docendo I have edited my question and the text which I want to replace

Comment: No need for the first and third `()`, `"^pred_(\\d+)_moves$" is sufficient.

Comment: @lmo, thanks, I left those out in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but I think you can use the function `gsub`;

Let's say that your dataframe is named `df`:

```
df$param <- gsub("pred", "Predicted", df$param)
df$param <- gsub("_", " ", df$param)
df$param <- gsub("moves", "Moves", df$param)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr) 

df$param <- recode(df$param, 'pred_1_moves' = 'Predicted 1 Moves', 'pred_2_moves' = 'Predicted 2 Moves', 'pred_3_moves' = 'Predicted 3 Moves')
```